# Microchip Wi-Fi MRF24WN0MA

Tags: microchip, wifi

I am using the following devices from Microchip on an embedded system:

- USB Starter Kit III (PIC32MX470F512L) + Starter Kit I/O expansion board
- MRF24WN0MA.

So I use the SPI1 channel for communication with a 6-axis sensor (all works fine). Then I want to transmit these data through the SPI2 to my WiFi module (MRF24WN0MA), I chose it because I need a wireless module with a minimum data rate of 1Mbits/s and a reliable communication.

I am using MPLAB Harmony v2_02_00b to configure the WiFi module. I have tested several example projects provided by Microchip as "wifi_easy_configuration", "wifi_ap_demo" and they don't work for me.
I followed [this tutorial](http://microchipdeveloper.com/harmony:migrating-hw-platforms) to migrate the project toward my PIC32

Comment: So, what is your question exactly?

Comment: If you have an idea about why i don't succeed in migrating these example projects to the PIC32MX470F512L just following the tutorial linked above? If anyone have already succeeded in using the MRF24WN module.

Furthermore, there isn't datasheet for this module's registers. So, without Harmony, i don't know how to do to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of documentation in the datasheet of this module and several other issues, i switched to the MRF24J40MA which has lower data rate but a complete datasheet (registers included!).